# Problem: Router changes the URL, but the all the component are not rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-component, react-context

I have components consum context api.  Each list item has a custom link to redirect to it's page.

I'm trying to render each list of component

For **"Product.jf, Details.js"** components i can render them. But, for "**Cart.js**" I can't.

I need your help to solve this problem.**

Thank you for your help

```js
{/* Section Component */}

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Cart from "../Section/Cart";
import Details from "../Section/Details";
import Products from "../Section/Products";

export class Section extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <Switch>
          {/* <Route path="/" component={Products} exact /> */}
          <Route path={"/product"} component={Products} exact />
          <Route path={"/product/:id"} component={Details} exact />
          <Route path={"/product/:id"} component={Details} exact />
          <Route exact path={"/cart"} component={Cart} exact />
        </Switch>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Section;
```

```js
{/* App Component*/}

import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import AppFooter from "./components/layouts/AppFooter";
import AppNavbar from "./components/layouts/AppNavbar";
import { DataProvider } from "./components/layouts/Context";
import Section from "./components/layouts/Section";


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DataProvider>
        <Router>
          <AppNavbar />
          <Section />
          <AppFooter />
        </Router>
      </DataProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
{/* Cart Component */}

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { DataContext } from "../layouts/Context";

export class Cart extends Component {
  static contextType = DataContext;

  render() {
    const { cart } = this.context;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Cart</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Cart;
```

[Project sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-paper-0hu2h?file=/src/components/)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem in [your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-paper-0hu2h?file=/src/components/) is that you aren't rendering your `App` component inside `index.js`, but something else. You also had a `Cart.js` file that you imported and used, but without anything inside it.

The routing part in the `Section` component works perfectly fine:

```
export class Section extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/product" component={Products} exact />
          <Route path="/product/:id" component={Details} />
          <Route path="/cart" component={Cart} />
        </Switch>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.js`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

`App.js`

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DataProvider>  
        <Router>
          <Section />
        </Router>
      </DataProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-bush-4k0wu?file=/src/components/Section.js)